# Subgroups of integers

Tags: group-theory

How do I show that $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ is a group?

I need to show that it has closure, is associative, has an identity element, and an inverse element. For closure, I simply computed the possibilities. Is there a more formal way of showing this? Also, how can I show associativity without computing all possibilities?

Comment: I'm mainly looking for a formal way to show in a proof that it is associative and has closure without computing all possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might be instructive to just check all of the axioms rather using a theorem that says that the cartesian product of two groups is a group under component wise multiplication.

For the subgroups, simply check what the elements of the group generate to be, the elements being (0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1).

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'm having a hard time finding an inverse element. Is there no inverse element, thus it is not a group?

Comment: By definition yes. However, I think You should look harder. Try multiplying an element by itself. What happens?

Answer (score 0):

Look at what happens in each of the following cases.

$\langle 0,0\rangle$, $\langle 1,0\rangle$, $\langle 0,1\rangle$, $\langle 1,1\rangle$